# Facebook comment plugin does not show in iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, plugins, fancybox, comments

I am trying to use facebook comment plugin in my fancybox (iframe) however for some reason the plugin does not load / show. Like plugin just next to the comment plugin works fine.

I am using HTML5 markup option. Is this a common issue and will it perhaps be resolved in the June 2013 changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried using the demo codes provided by Fancybox test out iframe and comment plugin, no issues. the iFrame is loading the following code file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fancyBox - iframe demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=327444117315763";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<h1>fancyBox - iframe demo</h1>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are right, I actually discovered a bug. I did not put the javascript init code into the fancyboxes point of view. My bad sorry.